# How to write enum in smartPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

How do we translate the below enum in smartPy.

```
enum ServiceType {
        REQUEST_COIN_TRANSFER,
        REQUEST_COIN_REGISTER,
        REPONSE_HANDLE_SERVICE,
        BLACKLIST_MESSAGE,
        CHANGE_TOKEN_LIMIT,
        UNKNOWN_TYPE
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartPy offers the variant system (see doc for [new](https://preview.smartpy.io/0.17.0-beta-02/docs/manual/syntax/options-and-variants#variants) and [legacy](https://smartpy.io/docs/types/variants/) syntax). It's more powerful than enum as they associate a value with a type so you can create enum with them and even more. Basically an enum is a variant with a `sp.unit` value.

I suggest you to take time to think how you can use the full power of it (not using a `sp.unit` value for each field.

**New syntax**

```
# Naming enum type
my_enum_type: type = sp.variant(REQUEST_COIN_TRANSFER=sp.unit, REQUEST_COIN_REGISTER=sp.unit...)

# Creating a value
my_value = sp.variant.REQUEST_COIN_TRANSFER(sp.unit)

# If the value is used somewhere the type isn't already enforced:
sp.cast(my_value, my_enum_type)
```

**Legacy syntax**

```
# Naming enum type
my_enum_type = sp.TVariant(REQUEST_COIN_TRANSFER=sp.TUnit, REQUEST_COIN_REGISTER=sp.TUnit...)

# Creating a value
my_value = sp.variant("REQUEST_COIN_TRANSFER", sp.unit)

# If the value is used somewhere the type isn't already enforced:
my_value = sp.set_type_expr(my_value, my_enum_type)
```

More examples can be found here: https://smartpy.io/ide?template=test_variant.py